# XAMPP redirects to dashboard instead of desired page

Tags: php, html, authentication, xampp

So I am using XAMPP but when I click on a link it redirects me to localhost/dashboard instead of the page I want. How can I fix this?

This is the code of the index page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SG Weredi</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="loginpagina.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


  <div class="header">
    <a href="/">Your App Name</a>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <img class =" logo" src="http://www.weredi.nl/logo.png">
  </div>

    <?php if( !empty($user) ): ?>

    <br />Welcome <?= $user['email']; ?> 
    <br /><br />You are successfully logged in!
    <br /><br />
    <a href="logout.php">Logout?</a>

  <?php else: ?>

    <h1>Please Login or Register</h1>
    <a href="Infproject/login.php">Login</a> or
    <a href="register.php">Register</a>

  <?php endif; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your .htaccess rewrite rules, please.

Comment: I already tried to delete the index.php file in the htdocs but I get to the localhost page. When i click on the project in redirects me to my index page but the links don't work either

Comment: what link are you clicking?

Comment: @HonzaRydrych where do I find them :)?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile for example the register.php link

Comment: is this inside a folder in htdocs?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile this is the root directory C:/xampp/htdocs/Infproject . all my files are in Infproject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only link that is correct is `<a href="register.php">Register</a>`.

You should do the same for login:

`<a href="login.php">Login</a>`

instead of

`<a href="Infproject/login.php">Login</a>`.

The same solution is for link to home page of project:

`<div class="header">
   <a href="./">Your App Name</a>
</div>`

instead of

`<div class="header">
   <a href="/">Your App Name</a>
</div>`

because `href="/"` on your site redirects you to `index.php` in `C:/xampp/htdocs` which redirects to `C:/xampp/htdocs/dashboard/` (`localhost/dashboard`).

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing port number to new one and restart the apache server.
I changed port number from 8082 to 8084 and restarted the server. This worked for me.